# Web Speech api not working on android chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, speech-recognition, webspeech-api

Web speech api (webkitSpeechRecognition) return 'not-allowed' error on android phone.

(I gave Microphone permission to chrome app and site on android settings)

**Chrome on desktop is working.
But, on android is not.**

(Test phone is Samsung Galaxy S9, Android Version 10, Chrome Version 86)

I tested MicrosoftEdge, SamsungInternet as well as Chrome on android.
but all returns **'not-allowed' error**.

Test Page
https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

test code on chrome remote device console.

```
const a = new webkitSpeechRecognition()
a.onerror = (err) => {console.log("err:", err)}
a.start()
=> VM187:1 err: SpeechRecognitionErrorEvent {isTrusted: true, error: "not-allowed", message: "", type: "error", target: SpeechRecognition, …}
```

Is it a android problem?
How can I make it working?

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware that it is a very old question.

In my case problem was caused by an invalid SSL certificate.
**Desktop** Chrome (Linux) was fine with that but **Android** Chrome was throwing "not-allowed" error. Fixing SSL certificate solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you. You just saved me tons of time and frustration. :)